# Extract multiple occurrences on the same line using sed/regex

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to loop through each line in a file and find and extract letters that start with `${` and end with `}`. So as the final output I am expecting only `SOLDIR` and `TEMP`(from `inputfile.sh`).

I have tried using the following script but it seems it matches and extracts only the second occurrence of the pattern `TEMP`. I also tried adding `g` at the end but it doesn't help. Could anybody please let me know how to match and extract both/multiple occurrences on the same line ?

*inputfile.sh:*

```
.  
.  
SOLPORT=\`grep -A 4 '\[LocalDB\]' \${SOLDIR}/solidhac.ini | grep \${TEMP} | awk '{print $2}'\`  
.  
.
```

*script.sh:*

```
infile='inputfile.sh'  
while read line ; do    
  echo $line | sed 's%.*${\([^}]*\)}.*%\1%g'  
done < "$infile"
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

May I propose a `grep` solution?

```
grep -oP '(?<=\${).*?(?=})'
```

It uses Perl-style [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and lazily matches anything between `'${'` and `'}'`.

Feeding your line to it, I get

```
$ echo "SOLPORT=\`grep -A 4 '[LocalDB]' \${SOLDIR}/solidhac.ini | grep \${TEMP} | awk '{print $2}'\`" | grep -oP '(?<=\${).*?(?=})'
SOLDIR
TEMP
```

Comment: Very useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (but maybe only for your specific input line):

```
sed 's/[^$]*\(${[^}]\+}\)[^$]*/\1\t/g;s/$[^{$]\+//g'
```

Answer (score 1):

Extracting multiple matches from a single line using sed isn't as bad as I thought it'd be, but it's still fairly esoteric and difficult to read:

```
$ echo 'Hello ${var1}, how is your ${var2}' | sed -En '
    # Replace ${PREFIX}${TARGET}${SUFFIX} with ${PREFIX}\a${TARGET}\n${SUFFIX}
    s#\$\{([^}]+)\}#\a\1\n#
    # Continue to next line if no matches.
    /\n/!b
    # Remove the prefix.
    s#.*\a##
    # Print up to the first newline.
    P
    # Delete up to the first newline and reprocess what's left of the line.
    D
'
var1
var2
```

And all on one line:

```
sed -En 's#\$\{([^}]+)\}#\a\1\n#;/\n/!b;s#.*\a##;P;D'
```

Since POSIX extended regexes don't support non-greedy quantifiers or putting a newline escape in a bracket expression I've used a `BEL` character (`\a`) as a sentinel at the end of the prefix instead of a newline. A newline could be used, but then the second substitution would have to be the questionable `s#.*\n(.*\n.*)##`, which might involve a pathological amount of backtracking by the regex engine.